Probability that one random variable is less/greater than another when they have the same distribution
The following is one of my statistics homework questions:
What is the median of the random variable $X$, such that $X \sim F_{m, n}$ when $m = n$?
The answer involves showing that this implies $X \sim F_{n, n}$, i.e. $\frac{U}{V}$, where $U, V \sim \chi^2_n$. Then it follows that $$\mathbb{P}(U > V) = \mathbb{P}(U < V) = 0.5.$$ Dividing through by $V$, one gets $$\mathbb{P}(X > 1) = \mathbb{P}(X < 1) = 0.5,$$ therefore $x = 1$ is the median of $X$.
Is the above result valid in general? Namely:
If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, then does it hold that $$\mathbb{P}(X > Y) = \mathbb{P}(X < Y) = 0.5?$$

What if they are the same random variable? In this case $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=1$.

Even if they're independent, this is not necessarily true: the two probabilities are equal due to symmetry, but $\Bbb P(X=Y)$ can still hold with positive probability (the most extreme case being if they are constant almost surely).

@GregMartin How to turn the "due to symmetry" into a formal proof though? It's not that obvious, and I believe is what OP is asking. Need to use joint distribution here.

@GregMartin The exercise involving this result featured two chi-squared variables, so I guess you could equivalently write $$\mathbb{P}(X \geq Y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq Y),$$ due to the distribution being continuous, to accommodate the case where $X = Y$. Could you please elaborate on 'due to symmetry'?

We can show this with the assumption that $P(X = Y) = 0$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The first assumption is always true for continuous random variables.
Firstly
$1 = P(\Omega) = P(\{X < Y\} \sqcup \{X > Y\} \sqcup \{X = Y\}) = P(X < Y) + P(X > Y) + P(X = Y)$.
Using assumption we get $P(X < Y) + P(X > Y) = 1$, therefore now we only need to show that $P(X < Y) = P(X > Y)$.
This can be shown using characteristic functions, using i.d.d: $\phi_{X-Y}(t)=\phi_{X}(t)\phi_{-Y}(t) = \phi_{Y}(t)\phi_{-X}(t) = \phi_{Y-X}(t)$, therefore $X - Y$ is symmetric around zero.
Alternatively, we can derive this $P(X < Y) = P(X > Y)$ directly from the definition with some more work. Notice that $$\{w: X(w) > Y(w)\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \coprod_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} \{w: X(w) \in [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}], Y(w)\notin [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}]\}$$
Therefore $$P(X > W) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} P(X \in [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}], Y \notin [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])$$
Now using independence $$P(X > W) =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} P(X \in [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])P( Y \notin [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])$$
Using i.d. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} P(X \in [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])P( Y \notin [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}]) = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} P(Y \in [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])P( X \notin [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i + 1}{2^n}])$$
Therefore $$P(X < Y) = P(X > Y) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
In this proof we used the following property: $A_{1} \subset A_2 \subset \ldots \Rightarrow P(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$. This is a general property of sigma-additive measures which is called continuity of measure. Let's prove it.
$P(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = P(A_1 \sqcup (\coprod_{n = 2}^{\infty} (A_n \ A_{n - 1}))) = P(A_1) + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} (P(A_n) - P(A_{n - 1}) = $
$P(A_1) + \lim_{n \to \infty} (P(A_n) - P(A_1)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$

Thank you for the detailed reply. I don't understand how you've defined ${w : X(w) > Y(w)}$. Also, is there any particular reason why you're using the disjoint union rather than the usual union?

Do you mean 'why is it measurable?'? By the definition $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is random variable if ${w: X(w) < a} \in \mathcal{A} , \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, where $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is the probability space. Therefore ${w: X(w) < Y(w)} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} {w: X(w) < q} \cap {w: Y(w) > q}\in \mathcal{A}$ as countable union/intersection of measurable sets.
As for your second question, I do so to use the additivity property of probability measure: $\mathbb{P}(\coprod A_i) = \sum \mathbb{P}(A_i)$.

Okay, I see. Thank you!

Your claim is not quite true:  for instance, if $X$ and $Y$ have a discrete probability mass, say $\Pr[X = k] > 0$ for some $k$ in the support of $X$, then $$\Pr[X = Y] \ge \Pr[(X = k) \cap (Y = k)] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \Pr[X = k]\Pr[Y = k] > 0,$$ from which it follows that $$\Pr[X > Y] + \Pr[X < Y] = 1 - \Pr[X = Y] < 1.$$  A simple numerical example would be if $X, Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$, in which case $$\Pr[X = Y] = p^2 + (1-p)^2,$$ and $$\Pr[X > Y] = \Pr[X < Y] = p(1-p).$$  For any $0 < p < 1$, this quantity is at most $1/4$.
This counterexample--iid discrete random variables--should elicit some additional thoughts about the conditions under which your claim would be true, and why those conditions are necessary for the proof of that claim.

Sorry, why is it the case that $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) \geq \mathbb{P}[(X = k) \cap (Y = k)]$?

Would the statement be true for continuous random variables?

@RiccardoIorio Think about the event $X = Y$.  It must include the joint event $X = k$ and $Y = k$, since the latter also implies the former.  So the probability $\Pr[X = Y]$ must be at least as large as the joint probability $\Pr[(X = k) \cap (Y = k)]$.

@RiccardoIorio It certainly seems like it could be true for a continuous random variable, right?  In particular, we would require $\Pr[X = Y] = 0$ for all outcomes of $X$ and $Y$.  So this imposes a restriction that they cannot have any discrete probability masses.  How would you go about formalizing this intuition?  Another strategy would be to think about a specific case, e.g., if $X$ and $Y$ iid uniform random variables, would it be true that $\Pr[X < Y] = \Pr[X > Y] = 0.5$?

Sorry, I just can't see how to proceed. Even in the particular case you've mentioned, how would you write down the probability that a random variable is less/greater than another random variable (not a specific value)? How would you construct the cdf?
